# WordPress : how to add an image upload button to the edit form?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to add an image upload button to the WordPress edit form and retrieve the ID of the uploaded media.

If it is possible, I want the user to click the button, choose his image on his computer and then display a tag containing the ID of the media in the textarea. Do you know a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: There are plugins that can do that. Make something like that from ground is a lot of work. It depends on your skills. Best if no skills, use a plugin for custom fields.

Comment: @rgdesign: It is for a plugin, so it will be better if there are no dependencies... Have you a link where I can find some information about this?

Comment: if you google something like "wordpress image upload custom field", you will get lot of information :)

Comment: Custom fields are made for adding metadata to the posts, all I want is a button that allows me to retrieve the ID of an image. But thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by myself how to add and use a media button. If someone else is searching for that, I wrote a tutorial about doing this on [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-a-media-button-to-the-content-editor/). You can also find a French version on [my blog](http://tassedecafe.org/2850-wordpress-bouton-media-editeur-partie-1.html).

Basically, it uses the action `media_buttons` which is currently not listed on the WordPress Codex. This action is called when media buttons are displayed in the WordPress editor: all you have to do is displaying your own button with a dedicated function.

Then, you can open a media window and retrieve the user's selection thanks to a good (but hidden!) API.